# How to write class for neural network to be able to access layers in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, oop

I have been training a network written in Tensorflow and all was well, but now I need to visualise some metrics related to the weights of the filters at each each layer. So I need to be able to access the layers, I know it's pretty simple when using Keras' `Model`, but I believe there is a better way to define the class using Tensorflow such that layers are accessible?

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Activation, Conv2D, BatchNormalization)
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

class neural_net():

    def __init__(self, x):

        self.x = x
        self.layers = self.predictor(self.x)
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(self.layers[3], self.x), name = 'mse_loss')
    
    def predictor(self, x):
        layer0 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(512,512,3), padding='same', name = 'conv1')(x)
        layer1 = Activation('relu')(layer0)
        layer2 = BatchNormalization()(layer1)
        pred = Conv2D(3, (3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same',name = 'decoded')(layer2)
        return [layer0,layer1,layer2,pred]

x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,512,512,3),name = 'x')
net = neural_net(x)
loss = net.loss
layers = net.layers
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

w=[]
for layer in net.layers():
    w.append(layer.get_weights())
```

This gives error:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'get_weights'

I have also seen some examples showing class with `build` and `call` methods but I couldn't figure how to use them for my case (limited knowledge of oop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you should do is use the Keras [Subclassing API](https://keras.io/api/models/model/#model-class) (if you can call it an API). Essentially, what it does is *inherit* from the Keras `Model` (a little like the Sequential API), and so you can use it the same. It will enable your model to emulate the behaviors of a Keras model, for instance, you'll be able to call `model.fit()` or `model.summary()`.

Then, you should define the layers in the constructor (the `__init__` part), which will set the layers as instance variables, and allow you to access the layers like `model.layer1`. The `call()` method you will need to define will determine it's behavior when the model is called (the tensors will pass through the layers). Other than that, everything will be done automatically because the behaviors have been pre-defined by the `Model` class.

Here's an example on how to do it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model

inputs = tf.random.uniform(shape=(8, 512, 512, 3), minval=0, maxval=1)


class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.layer0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
            padding='same', name='conv1')
        self.layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')
        self.layer2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        x = self.layer0(x)
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        return x


model = MyModel()

model.build(input_shape=(1, 512, 512, 3))

model(inputs)
```

You will also be able to access the individual layers like you're used to:

```
model.layers
```

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x2d337c4b9c8>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Activation at 0x2d337c460c8>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization_v2.BatchNormalization at 0x2d337c465c8>]
```

If you want to integrate the loss and predict function to the model itself, I'm afraid it will require some level of skill with OOP.

Let me know if anything is missing from my answer. You can find similar Subclassing API examples with toy datasets in one of my [repos](https://github.com/nicolas-gervais/tensorflow-dump), namely with the MNIST and Iris dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a list like you suggested and put the layers into it. Then you can modify your `predictor` method to iterate the layers and call them in the right order. Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Activation, Conv2D, BatchNormalization)
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

class neural_net():

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.x = x
        self.layers = [Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(512,512,3), padding='same', name = 'conv1'), 
                       Activation('relu'), 
                       BatchNormalization(), 
                       Conv2D(3, (3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same',name = 'decoded')]
        self.pred = self.predictor(self.x)
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(self.pred, self.x), name = 'mse_loss')
    
    def predictor(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x)
        return x

x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,512,512,3),name = 'x')
net = neural_net(x)
loss = net.loss
pred = net.pred
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)
```

While I think this is what you meant, I doubt this would work like you expect it to. What is the exact reason you do not want to use the api provided by Keras? You can get the weights by iterating over the layers as well like you said.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! This seems to work. Why do you think this might be not be a good idea? I could try and use Keras' `Model` API if that is better, but Tensorflow by itself seems to give much more control so I got used to it, I was running into complications when trying to convert the code.

Comment: I had some doubts about whether loss value will get updated or not. But I guess if you are using tensorflow, then the computational graph should make it possible and no errors will occur. If my suggestion works for your use case, consider accepting my answer.

Comment: I see you edited your question. The problem with your updated code is that you are putting the _outputs_ of the layers into a list and not the layers themselves. Use the code I provided, where layers are in the list and self.predictor is calling these layers.

Comment: I don't think it's proper to ask a user to accept an answer when the question is recent and there are other quality answers. If OP gave feedback that your answer was everything he needed, or that significant time has passed since the question was asked, or if there were no other answers, that would be a different story. But when there are other answers and other answers have _just_ been posted, I would say that's not good practice.

Comment: OP said that my answer seemed to work and based on this I asked them to consider accepting my answer if it really solved their problem. I do not see how this is inappropriate and it was not my intention to get my answer accepted instead of yours. I apologize if this is what is seemed like to you.